# How can I reduce this code javascript code so it's not as repetitve?

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, recursion, refactoring

I have a function which goes through every name in an object. This object has an array parameter *materials* which holds other objects. Those objects have the same array parameter which hold more objects and so on.

My code lines 3-5 just repeat while adding .material and another variable. Also the code will only go into an object's name four layers down or else I have to keep repeating more code.

How can I cut down on this mess?

```
var itemList = function(x) {
    console.log(x.materials[0].name);
for (var i = 1; i < x.materials.length; i++) {
    console.log(x.materials[i].name);
    if (x.materials[i].build !== "BasicFactory" && i !== 0) {
        for (var j = 1; j < x.materials[i].materials.length; j++) {
            console.log(x.materials[i].materials[j].name);
            if (x.materials[i].materials[j].build !== "BasicFactory" && j !== 0) {
                for (var k = 1; k < x.materials[i].materials[j].materials.length; k++) {
                console.log(x.materials[i].materials[j].materials[k].name);
                if (x.materials[i].materials[j].materials[k].build !== "BasicFactory" && j !== 0) {
                    for (var l = 1; l < x.materials[i].materials[j].materials[k].materials.length; l++) {
                    console.log(x.materials[i].materials[j].materials[k].materials[l].name);
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Please ask at [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: underscore.js or loadsh.js ideal for such situations.

Comment: You want to use functional-style functions like `map` or `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to iterate and get the key/value pairs, and `filter` to remove other values:

```js
function foo(value, index)
  {
  if (value.hasOwnProperty("name")) return value.name; else return null;
  }

function bar(value)
  {
  if (value) return value;
  }

var baz = 
[
    1,
    2,
    {name:[1,
           2,
           {name:[1,2,3]}
          ]
    }
].map(foo).filter(bar);

console.log(baz);
```

> Sometimes we might want to get the transformation or the mapping of the original array. JavaScript provides a HOF for that too: map. This function has a signature, as follows:

```
array.map(callback,[ thisObject])
```

> This method also applies callback functions for each element of an array (again, only in the required context of this, and only for existing items). It does however also return the transformed (mapped) array as a result.
>
> Instead of the basic mapped result, we may want to only get certain entries that satisfy a certain condition, for example ones that have an email address that starts with "d". We can create a filter for exactly this kind of purpose, which will exclude items that don't pass our conditions. The filter method can be used to do this quickly and easily.
>
> The signature is quite similar to that of map:

```
array.filter(callback,[ thisObject])
```

> The callback function of the filter should return the boolean value (either true or false). true means that the filter is passed, and false means that an item shouldn’t be included in the result set.

**References**

- [Array Extras in Detail](https://dev.opera.com/articles/javascript-array-extras-in-detail/)